# Core Data with the Dimension class

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios10, nsmanagedobject

I have a variable:

```
var unit: Dimension = UnitMass.grams
```

How should I store/represent this as an attribute in Core Data? Could someone give an example too, please?

Can I do something like this:

```
@NSManaged var unit: Dimension
```

Thanks.